# Load all data at once, but show only 15 - JQGrid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

Is it possible to load all the table contents at once but show only 15 per page?
For example, I have a record count of 30 total, but when I fire up and populate my `JqGrid` table with `JSON` data, it'll load all 30 rows but show only 15 on the first page, and 15 on the other page.

The reason behind this question is when you have `multiselect` on and when you click the header checkbox, it will only check those in the current page and will not include those on the other pages.

Comment: gmail also does that way of you select aal from the inbox the currently shown emails are selected, whether you choose between client side pagination or the server side the user doesnot need to know about it,

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is property in jqGrid `loadonce:true` and set your `rowNum:15`

Comment: `it'll load all 30 rows but show only 15 on the first page, and 15 on the other page.`

Comment: Unfortunately, it'll ONLY load the first 15, no more second pages or the next 15 rows. :(